# LifecycleException when starting Apache James 2.3.2.1

Tags: apache, mail-server, james

When I try to start Apache James 2.3.2.1 using `bin/run.bat` file in windows 64-bit environment,it throws exception

```
ERROR   2017-01-13 14:48:18.285 [Phoenix.] (): Component named "users-store" failed to pass through the Starting stage. (Reason: org.apache.avalon.framework.configuration.ConfigurationException: destination>>URL).
ERROR   2017-01-13 14:48:18.286 [Phoenix.] (): There was an error running phase "startup" for Block named "users-store". (Reason: Component named "users-store" failed to pass through the Starting stage. (Reason:       org.apache.avalon.framework.configuration.ConfigurationException: destination>>URL).).
org.apache.avalon.phoenix.containerkit.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Component named "users-store" failed to pass through the Starting stage. (Reason: org.apache.avalon.framework.configuration.ConfigurationException: destination>>URL).
at org.apache.avalon.phoenix.containerkit.lifecycle.LifecycleHelper.fail(LifecycleHelper.java:354)
at org.apache.avalon.phoenix.containerkit.lifecycle.LifecycleHelper.startup(LifecycleHelper.java:226)
at org.apache.avalon.phoenix.components.application.DefaultApplication.startup(DefaultApplication.java:530)
at org.apache.avalon.phoenix.components.application.DefaultApplication.doRunPhase(DefaultApplication.java:478)
at org.apache.avalon.phoenix.components.application.DefaultApplication.runPhase(DefaultApplication.java:409)
at org.apache.avalon.phoenix.components.application.DefaultApplication.start(DefaultApplication.java:180)
at org.apache.avalon.framework.container.ContainerUtil.start(ContainerUtil.java:260)
rethrown from     org.apache.avalon.framework.configuration.ConfigurationException: destination>>URL
at org.apache.james.userrepository.UsersFileRepository.configure(UsersFileRepository.java:134)
```

I have checked in all config and searched for any properties file referring any such property,but with no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was with the James version being used.I switched over to version 2.3.2,which was working without any hassles.This version was available on [James 2.3.2](http://ftp.riken.jp/net/apache/james/server/)

The issue is mentioned in [this](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/JAMES-1631) post on Jira.Here the reported figured out the issue,due to change in one of the source classes,referring to URL from `config.xml` file.Quoting from error reporter:

> I discovered that by changing the default provided configuration file
>   (apps\james\SAR-INF\config.xml) and adapting 
>     And putting a
>   real name there, the original error goes away. Note that it did not
>   happen in James 2.3.2 I had a look in the source code and it's due to
>   this new code in UsersFileRepository